# adding multiple rows in oracle script while regarding created columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find a good way to add the multiple rows in a script while using created column names.  These are the database results I'm trying to manipulate and my script below.

```
PERSONID       myState      myAmount 
-----------------------------------
1               FL           100
1               TX           75
1               TX           50
1               FL           50 
1               FL           80
1               TX           55

Select PERSONID, (function to retrieve state) 
AS myState, (function to retrieve Amount) AS SUM(myAmount)
FROM Table
Group by myState
```

I'm expecting my results to be

```
PERSONID       myState      myAmount 
-----------------------------------
1               FL           230
1               TX           180
```

The script above does not work for me. I get "FROM Keyword not found where expected" or "myAmount; Invalid identifier". I also tried putting the SUM( around the function to retrieve amount but it says "not a single-group function".  What's a good way to modify the script to get the expected value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery or CTE:

```
select personid, mystate, SUM(myAmount)
from (select PERSONID, (function to retrieve state) AS myState,
             (function to retrieve Amount) 
      from Table
     ) p
group by personid, mystate;
```